# VBA Error 1004 - QueryTable.Add

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am getting a very strange error in VBA (1004) when trying to import a csv file.

Here is my code:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "IJR" & ".csv", Destination _
    :=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "IJR"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = xlMacintosh
    .TextFileStartRow = 2
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(3, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1)
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .UseListObject = False
End With
```

It gives me the error on `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False`.

IJR.csv **IS** a file in the same directory as my workbook. I have a bunch of csv files in the directory. The strange thing is, when I change "IJR" to "AA" or "HES" (which are also csv files in the directory), the code works. Most of the csv filenames do not work ("USO.csv", "AAL.csv", "AAPL.csv", "HD.csv", etc.), however a few of them do (so far just "AA.csv" and "HES.csv"). Theyre all identically formatted csv files with the same number of columns. I am completely at a loss. Maybe I'm making some bonehead error, but I can't spot it.

Another bit of useful info: I am running Excel 2016 for Mac. I have a very similar piece of code that runs if the OS is Windows (due to small differences in the VBA code for Mac and Windows). It works for every csv file, no issue. That code, for reference, is:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & symb & ".csv", Destination _
    :=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = symb
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 2
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(3, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Update 3/10/16:
I got it to work in Excel 2011 for Mac (by changing the "/" in the path to Application.PathSeparator), but it still does the same thing in Excel 2016 for Mac. May just be a bug in the new Excel.

Comment: If the same code works for some CSV files and not for others, I would guess the issue is some difference between the CSV files.  What happens when you just open these files in Excel (instead of adding the `QueryTable`)?  Do they open?  Look correct?

Comment: They all open and look correct. Again, everything works fine with Excel 13 for Windows. It's only when I try it in Excel 16 for Mac that I have this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a similar problem and after thorough testing I'm convinced this is a big in Excel 2016 for Mac and has not been fixed at 28 July 2017.

The workaround you might be able to use is:

- Import each of your text files manually.
- Then delete the connection (and the data).
- Once you have imported a file at a location ONCE, you can do so again using VBA.

Unfortunately this is not really dynamic, and will not work in cases like my where folders actually change.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I've found a better solution:

The actual (completely hidden) problem is that the sandbox security mode does not allow access to that file, and does not prompt you as it should. Read more about this http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac034.htm.

My workaround is to open the file using "Open", which prompts for the permission. We don't do anything with the open file. After permission is granted your code above will work.

```vba
Dim MyData As String, strData() As String

Open "/Users/myuser/Documents/myfile.csv" For Binary As #1 
MyData = Space$(LOF(1)) 
Get #1, , MyData 
Close #1
```

Comment: excellent answer. here's an updated link (above has expired): https://macexcel.com/examples/setupinfo/sandbox/index.html